# How to get complete list of programs installed on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a way print out a **complete** list of **all programs installed** on a  Windows Server 2012 R2 machine?

"Uninstall or change a program" programs doesn't seem to show everything.  We have also tried a powershell command Get-ItemProperty as well, but in both cases, they missed a program that's installed named Cygwin.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I think you are unlikely to come up with a good answer. There are -too many- ways of installing a program on Windows. All the way from COPY this .exe or .bat file somewhere to using .msi files. There may be a vendor who has tried to keep up with all (or many) of the install methods, but the product is unlikely to be free.